# MySQL correlated subquery at FROM

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I'm working with the [Sakila sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html), and trying to get the most viewed film per country. So far I've managed to get the most viewed film of a certain country given its id with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    F.title, CO.country, count(F.film_id) as times
FROM 
    customer C 
INNER JOIN 
    address A ON C.address_id = A.address_id
INNER JOIN 
    city CI ON A.city_id = CI.city_id
INNER JOIN 
    country CO ON CI.country_id = CO.country_id
INNER JOIN 
    rental R ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id
INNER JOIN 
    inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
INNER JOIN 
    film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id
WHERE 
    CO.country_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    F.film_id
ORDER BY 
    times DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I supose that I'll have to use this query or something similar in the FORM of another query, but I've tried it all I could think and am completely unable to figure out how to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit, this is a hell of a query. But well, as long as it works.

Explanation:

- Subquery: almost the same as you already has. Without the `WHERE` and `LIMIT`. Resulting in a list of movie-count per country
- Result of that, grouped per country
- `GROUP_CONCAT(title ORDER BY times DESC SEPARATOR '|||')`, will give ALL titles in that 'row', with the most-viewed title first. The separator doesn't matter, as long as you are sure it will never occurs in a title.
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX('...', '|||', 1)` results in the first part of the string until it finds `|||`, in this case the first (and thus most-viewed) title

Full query:

```
SELECT
    country_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(title ORDER BY times DESC SEPARATOR '|||'), 
        '|||', 1
    ) as title,
    MAX(times)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        F.title AS title, 
        CO.country_id AS country_id,
        CO.country AS country_name, 
        count(F.film_id) as times
    FROM customer C INNER JOIN address A ON C.address_id = A.address_id
    INNER JOIN city CI ON A.city_id = CI.city_id
    INNER JOIN country CO ON CI.country_id = CO.country_id
    INNER JOIN rental R ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id
    INNER JOIN inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id
    GROUP BY F.film_id, CO.country_id
) AS count_per_movie_per_country
GROUP BY country_id
```

Proof of concept (as long as the subquery is correct): [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a05e1e/5)

Comment: This doesen't seem to be working correctly, wich probably is due to my subquerry not being correct

Comment: You are correct. I missed a `GROUP BY` country. I've updated my answer, can you recheck?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, it's working correctly